# Energy Level data empty in Instruments

Tags: ios, xcode, instruments, xcode-instruments

Trying to pinpoint where my app is eating up phone battery via the Instruments Energy Log.

I record use of the app from an untethered iPhone ([as instructed by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/MeasuringEnergyImpact.html)), and have tried older suggestions.

However, as shown below, Energy Usage Level never show any data:

[image]

Why is energy usage level not showing up, even though I am recording the session from an untethered iPhone and importing into Instruments?

Comment: Did you manage to fix this issue?

Comment: @VasilNunev Unfortunately not, I had to move on

Comment: I did find out that for now the Battery Usage Level is empty for iOS 10 devices, we have to test on iOS 9 for the time being.

Comment: @VasilNunev Thanks for sharing - maybe it is an iOS10 bug?

Comment: I have the same problem in iPhone X on iOS 13.6.1.

Comment: Same issue iOS 14.2, iPhone 12 Pro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved in latest iOS Version
Xcode:8.3.2 and above ;
iOS Version: 10.3.1 and above

Comment: I'm running iOS 10.3.3 and Xcode v8.3.3 and I still see an empty Energy Usage Level section in the Instruments dashboard.

Comment: @SrAn I'm working with a legacy app and I'm using Xcode 8.2.1. Do you have any references that Apple fixed the issue?